# Which Thai provinces don't allow inter-provincial travel?

Tags: thailand, covid-19

I read on https://mobile.twitter.com/RichardBarrow/status/1273991585147965440  ([mirror](http://archive.is/wip/JKrv9)):

> Inter-provincial travel is now allowed to most provinces

Which Thai provinces don't allow inter-provincial travel?

---

Addressing some downvotes: the author of the tweets is one of the most knowledgeable individuals on traveling in Thailand. [He was praised for his tweets by the UK ambassador in Thailand](https://mobile.twitter.com/RichardBarrow/status/1243204481182924800)  ([mirror](https://archive.vn/wip/FPtQv)). Information is hard to find because the most up-to-date information is typically in Thai: the Thai government and agencies often only release information in Thai. The question is relevant for the 70 millions of people currently in Thailand

Comment: Downvoters: any comment for me to improve the question?

Comment: With all do respect, Franck, I share this link: https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask This question is based off of some random person's Twitter post (I would say a vague question), it doesn't appear any research was done, and I fail to see how it's relevant to anybody other than the reader of that Twitter post. Hence my downvote.

Comment: @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain Thanks. The author of the tweets is one of the most knowledgeable individuals on traveling in Thailand. He was praised for his tweets by the UK ambassador in Thailand. Information is hard to find because the most up-to-date information is typically in Thai. Does that now satisfy the how to ask requirements?

Answer (score 3):

The best I could find so far, quite outdated, from
https://thethaiger.com/coronavirus/14-thai-provinces-apply-travel-restrictions-for-residents:

> The 14 provinces and the dates for travel restrictions:
>
> - Chiang Rai, 9 – 30 April
> - Tak, 2 – 16 April
> - Nan, 5 – 17 April
> - Phrae 10 – 17 April
> - Bung Karn, 7 – 30 April
> - Phuket, 30 March – 30 April
> - Songkhla, 6 – 30 April
> - Satun, 3 – 30 April
> - Trat from 4 April until further notice
> - Pattani from 28 March until further notice
> - Yala from 29 March until further notice
> - Narathiwat from 29 March until further notice
> - Pattaya City from 9 April until further notice
> - Ranong from 6 April until further notice

According to https://redd.it/hcziyb, as of now (2020-06-22) no Thai province ban inter-provincial travel, but some means of transportations have some restrictions.